# Where can I buy Liefmans Fruitesse In Ontario?

Tags: distribution

This beer used to be available from the LCBO but now outside of Kegs or going to a bar it doesn't seem that I can get it anymore. Does anyone know the best way I could get a hold of it?

Comment: I don't know a dealer in Ontario, but you can contact [Gregory Mconway](http://www.ratebeer.com/user/330442/), because he lives in Ontario and has rated [Liefmans Fruitesse](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/liefmans-fruitesse-kriek/24689/) I hope this is useful for your research.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy it online from [The Gull Liquor Store](https://gullliquorstore.com/product/liefmans-fruitesse-4x-250ml/) in BC.

[image: Liefmans Fruitesse]

Liefmans Fruitesse from [The Gull Liquor Store](https://gullliquorstore.com/contact/)!

900–333 Brooksbank Ave.

North Vancouver, BC

Phone: 1-604-988-5545

E-mail: info@gullliquorstore.com

Comment: But the Gull Liquor Store is in BC and not Ontario.

Comment: Yes, I know. At least it's not too far (and most importantly: online).

Comment: 3000 kilometres isn't far? In any case, despite having a web site, they do not offer delivery: "NOTICE:
WE CURRENTLY DO NOT OFFER DELIVERY. ALL ITEMS PURCHASED ARE FOR PICKUP IN STORE."  https://gullliquorstore.com/cart/ Selling and shipping alcohol out of province is probably illegal anyways.

Answer (score 2):

The [Village Idiot Pub](http://Liefmans%20Fruitesse) (126 McCaul St Toronto, Ontario M5T 1W2) sells Liefmans Fruitesse.

Here is what they say about this craft beer:

> **Liefmans Fruitesse**
>
> 4.2% alc./vol. 33CL
>    A fresh Belgian beer blend, maturing for 18 months on cherries in Liefmans cellars, artfully blended with natural juices of strawberry, raspberry, cherry, blueberry and juniper berry resulting in a fruity, pleasantly sweet, sparkling and refreshing beer.

Here is what the LCBO has to say about this must try craft Beer:

> Red Berry
>
> Yes, “red berry”, because there’s some excellent combos out there. Both of our winners in this category come out of Belgium, but can be found in LCBOs and pubs around Ontario.
>
> **Liefmans Fruitesse** bills itself as an appetizer beer. It’s a deep red, cranberry juice colour, sparkling, and oh-so-juicy. It also tastes something like cranberry juice,  with a bit more sweetness, and a nice alcoholic kick. Like how you (or at least Jess) wish wine would taste. There’s no cranberry involved though; it’s actually cherry, raspberry, elderberry, strawberry, and bilberry. - [Best Fruit Beers You Can Find Locally](http://hoppily-ever-after.com/tag/lcbo/)

Comment: Yeah I know the bars in Toronto you can get it (that's one, you can also get it at Prenup and Town Crier), I want to get bottles of it. They used to be in the LCBO but no longer.